# FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent

Activity A started B, now the Activity stack will be A,B (B at top).
Now from Activity B i started Activity A by using intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT , now the Activity stack will be B,A(A at top).
Again I tried starting Activity B from Activity A using intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, which results in bringing Activity B to front but destroying activity A.

Comment: Is this a tongue-twister, or something? JK, you have to explain with more details and put some code of what you have tried so far, thanks.

Comment: Activity A start B --> Activity stack will be A,B.

In order to get the background Activity A to foreground
Activity B start A using intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT --> Activity stack will be B,A.

Again if I tried to get the background Activity B to foreground using the same FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT intent, results in bringing Activity B to top and killing Activity A.

Comment: This should work just fine. If A is getting destroyed there is something else going on. Please post your manifest.

Comment: @DavidWasser
  These are the two activities in manifest

<activity
            android:name="ActivityA"
            android:label="activitya"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

<activity
            android:name="ActivityB"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

</activity>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `launchMode="singleTask"`from your manifest. This is causing your problem. Also get rid of `clearTaskOnLaunch="false"`, this is the default setting you don't need to specify this.